# PHP: Collect all variables passed to a function as array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I was thinking about the possibility of accessing all the variables that are passed into an function, and merge them into an array. (Without passing variables into an array from the beginning)

Pseudo-code:

```
// Call function
newFunction('one', 'two', 'three' ) ;// All values are interpreted as a one rray in some way

// Function layout
newFunction( ) {    
   // $functionvariables =  array( All passed variables) 

    foreach ($functionvariable as $k => $v) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://php.net/func_get_args

Comment: Can't believe how easy that was. Thanks a lot for one of the fastest answers on SO I have gotten this far :)

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at **[`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)** function. This is how you can build an array for them:

```
function test()
{
  $numargs = func_num_args();

  $arg_list = func_get_args();
  $args = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++)
  {
    $args[] = $arg_list[$i];
  }

  print_r($args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful to clearly identify that the items you are passing in should be treated as an array. For instance, set your function def to

```
function newFunction( $arrayOfArguments ) { 
    foreach($arrayOfArguments as $argKey => $argVal)
    { /* blah */ }
}
```